# Scala : Can not refer user defined abstract class inside main method in same file

Tags: scala

I am following "Functional Programming in Scala" on Coursera and came across following code block:

```
package com.learning

class Learning_1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      IntSet empty = Empty     

  }

}

abstract class IntSet {

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet

  def contain(x: Int): Boolean
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = {
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this

  }

  def contain(x: Int): Boolean = {

    if (x < elem) left.contain(x)
    else if (x > elem) right.contain(x)
    else true
  }

}

object Empty extends IntSet {

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, Empty, Empty)

  def contain(x: Int): Boolean = false
}
```

I am getting compilation error `Cannot resolve symbol IntSet` in main method. I am not able to understand, why `IntSet` is not visible in same file. The complete file has been named as `Learning_1.scala`

I have spent 2 days in searching solution but no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare variables using a Java-like syntax. In Scala use `val` or `val` followed by the variable name, then a colon, then the type.

You meant to say

```
class Learning_1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val empty: IntSet = Empty
  }
}
```

Comment: Ray Toal, Thanks a lot your answer. You saved my day.